# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '501 <>: missing or malformed local part

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling

Hi guys all of a sudden I'm getting this error in my Zend program where I am trying to send an email. I have no idea whats wrong here :(

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '501 <>: missing or malformed local part
```

It was working fine till a few days back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be you have invalid local part of domain? like myapp.localhost?